# Random given name

Tags: random, entity

How to take a 3 random given name?

I tried:

[image]

Comment: `RandomEntity["GivenName", 3]`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO the best way is [`RandomEntity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomEntity.html) as [C.E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) points out in the comments:

```
RandomEntity["GivenName", 3]
```

[image]

But another (deterministic) way is with the property `"SampleEntities"`:

```
Take[EntityValue["GivenName", "SampleEntities"], UpTo[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use RandomChoice[ ] to get your random names:

```
list = EntityList["GivenName"];
RandomChoice[list, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this improves on the original situation.  Running this now and it looks like it will take an hour to grab the whole list.

Comment: You only have to download the list once. After that, it should be stored locally. In the program, you can then call RandomChoice many times and sicen it operates on `list` it is (nearly) instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the Wolfram Function Repository function [`RandomPetName`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomPetName/):

```mathematica
SeedRandom[33];
ResourceFunction["RandomPetName"][6]

(* {"Alphie", "Clef", "Dawg", "Xio Xin", "Cheyenne", "Audie"} *)
```

---

A few of the names from the other answers *might be* generated by `RandomPetName`:

```mathematica
Cases[Normal[Normal /@ ResourceFunction["RandomPetName"][All]], 
  "Elizabeth" | "Michael" | "Melady" | "Jacob" | "Sue" | "Sauna" | 
   "Teko", Infinity] // Union

(* {"Elizabeth", "Jacob", "Michael", "Sue"} *)
```